# How to detect different scrollTop positions

Tags: scrolltop

I would like to detect different greater than scrollTop position as follows: I want if window is greater than 100px add a class to body and if it is again larger than 150 remove that class and add another class.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll >= 100)  {
      $('body').addClass('one');
   }
   else (scroll >= 150)  {
      $('body').addClass('two');
      $('body').removeClass('one')
   }
});
```

It is working only applying (if condition) but not working with multiple positions by using (else condition).

Comment: Well, 150 is also greater than 100... Maybe you should swap around the if conditions?

Comment: can you show an example as i am not much very good in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is basic control flow, your second conditional is redundant because if scroll is >= 150 then it is definitely >= 100 which means you'll never reach that second block:

```
if (scroll >= 100) {
    // execute if scroll is greater or equal to 100
} else if (scroll >= 150) {
    // execute if scroll is NOT greater or equal to 100
    // execute if scroll is greater or equal to 150
}
```

You would need to swap them round like so:

```
if (scroll >= 150) {
    // execute if scroll is greater or equal to 150
} else if (scroll >= 100) {
    // execute if scroll is NOT greater or equal to 150
    // execute if scroll is greater or equal to 100
}
```

You also have a syntax error here: `else (scroll >= 150)  {` should be `else if (...`

Comment: Now I corrected code as follows...but nothing happening.

    $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100)  {
    $('body').addClass('one');
    }
    else if (scroll >= 150)  {
    $('body').addClass('two');
    $('body').removeClass('one')
    }
    });

Comment: Reread my answer before the last line. That `if..else if` will never reach the `else if` in its current state. You need to check `>= 150` before `>= 100` because `>= 150` will _always_ be `>= 100`.